# Windows 2003 Webserver blocking all incomming connections

Tags: windows

I am experiencing a problem where my windows 2003 server is  blocking all incoming connections. On rebooting I can ping it for a some seconds while it is starting up  but when the log in prompt appears, I am unable to ping it at all. An nmap shows no ports open and I have stopped the firewall service but I still have the issue.

Comment: Are you pinging by name or IP? If by name, is it resolving correctly? Are you pinging your server from 1 PC or did you try many PC's?

Comment: By IP, even buy name it does not work. Something is closing down the ports

Comment: But all you other devices can ping each other? The issue is only with the Sever 2003?

Comment: Please try netstat as well, just to confirm your findings. To list open ports and listening services, then from within command prompt, type *netstat -a*